# The average Jitter calculated in Iperf

Tags: delay, iperf

In the RFC 1889 the delay jitter is given by

```
J=J+(|(Rj-Sj)-(Ri-Si)|-J)/16
```

I use iperf to measure delay jitters between two network nodes. I got

```
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  18.7 KBytes   153 Kbits/sec   8.848 ms    0/   13 (0%)
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  15.8 KBytes   129 Kbits/sec   8.736 ms    0/   11 (0%)
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  15.8 KBytes   129 Kbits/sec  17.437 ms    0/   11 (0%)
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  15.8 KBytes   129 Kbits/sec  15.929 ms    0/   11 (0%)
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  12.9 KBytes   106 Kbits/sec  11.942 ms    0/    9 (0%)
[  3]  0.0- 5.0 sec  80.4 KBytes   131 Kbits/sec  18.451 ms    0/   56 (0%)
```

I want to know jitters every second and do statistics but I found I can't calculate the average jitter at the end of the iperf report. 
What's the relationship of jitter between the average and every-second record.